Is there any way I can differentiate objects that are supported by standard list controller from the ones which are not..?
I've been trying to create a code using schema that returns a list of objects which can be used with standard list controller. I know the 13 names of those 13 objects (Account, Asset, Campaign, Case, Contact, Contract, Idea, Lead, Opportunity, Order, Product2, Solution, User) but what is it that give these objects this extra access

See this document: mentions the supported object in the standard list controller.

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to clarify what you mean by "I couldn't figure the difference".

couldnt figure the difference between what? Please share the code sample that you have implemented / referred for better clarity on your question

@MonalisaDas I think the question is clear. Which objects are suported by a standard list controller?

The list of supported objects is found at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_about.htm
Standard list controllers allow you to create Visualforce pages that can display or act on a set of records. Examples of existing Salesforce pages that work with a set of records include list pages, related lists, and mass action pages. Standard list controllers can be used with the following objects:

Account
Asset
Campaign
Case
Contact
Contract
Idea
Lead
Opportunity
Order
Product2
Solution
User
Custom objects

